# Does Visual Studio have center of screen typing mode? I.e. keep focus of input in vertical middle of screen

Tags: visual-studio

Can I get the editor to keep the current input in the vertical center of the window?

So that the page text auto scrolls.

Comment: In your application or one of the Visual Studio designers?

Comment: in the Visual Studio editor.  Not in an application.

Answer (score 4):

I found something useful for what I wanted, but would still like centered typing focus mode.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> – moves view up one line at a time,  so the text scrolls 'down' one line at a time
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> – moves view down one line at a time,  so the text scrolls 'up' one line at a time